# Как конвертить session/tdata telegram файл в json

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Я хочу конвертировать telegram файл с расширением *.session в json, в котором хочу получить такой вид: `{"session_file": "6285351202414", "phone": "6285351202414", "register_time": 1665007347, "app_id": id, "app_hash": "hash", "sdk": "iOS", "app_version": "1.52.10 Z", "device": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/100.0.5120.93 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1", "last_check_time": 1666735347, "avatar": "img/default.png", "first_name": "TGBOSS", "last_name": "Accounts", "username": "shykhiworyvi2", "sex": 1, "lang_pack": "en", "system_lang_pack": "en-US", "twoFA": "shykhiworyvi2_5631309146", "ipv6": false, "status": "ok", "status_time": 1666735347, "is_old": false, "proxy": []}`

Пытался реализовать через метод get_me() с помощью библиотеки telethon. Возвращает другие параметры, которых не хватает. С телетоном работаю впервые, буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно владеть данными отдельно, такими как application hash, id, system version и так далее. В телетоне их все не достать, поэтому при подключении с неверными параметрами аккаунт с большой вероятностью будет забанен.

Вам необходимо иметь больше изначальных данных для регистрации сессии.